# Masonry - Safari height:auto

Tags: css, safari, height, article

I'm using **Masonry** for the double columns system, but Safari does not read the height of the **articles**.

Firefox (28.0) and Chrome (34.0.1847.131) display perfectly but Safari 7.0.3 (9537.75.14) instead sovvrappone the articles, because they do not understand the property `height: auto;`

```
article{
   margin:0 0 20px 0;
   padding:0 0 20px 0;
   width:340px;
   float:left;
   background:#fff;
   display:block;
   height:auto;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: `height:auto;` did not work. Try using `height: 100% !important;` for the image container. Not for `<img />`tag.

Comment: I tried but the article become smaller.

Comment: Can you provide me your site address? try removing the height: auto, height: 100%;

Comment: This is the result of height:100%;
http://www.iulianrusu.it/stackoverflow/height_100.png